# Aws lambda java - Implement simple cache to read a file

Tags: caching, aws-lambda

I have a lambda process in java and it reads a json file with a table everytime is triggered. I'd like to implement a kind of cache to have that file in memory and I wonder how to do something simple. I don't want to use elasticchache or redis.

I read something similar to my approach in javascript declaring a global variable with let but not sure how to do it in java, where it should be declared and how to test it. Any idea or example you can provide me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- There are `global variables` in lambda which can be of help but they have to be used wisely.
- They are usually the variables declared out side of `lambda_handler`.
- There are pros and cons of using it.
- You can't rely on this behavior but you must be aware it exists. When you call your Lambda function several times, you **MIGHT** get the same container to optimise run duration and setup delay [Use of Global Variables](https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2018/08/27/improving-performance-from-your-lambda-function-from-the-use-of-global-variables/)
- At the same time you should be aware of the issues or avoid wrong use of it [caching issues](https://medium.com/tensult/aws-lambda-function-issues-with-global-variables-eb5785d4b876)
- If you don't want to use `ElastiCache`/`redis` then i guess you have very less options left.......may be `dynamoDB` or `S3` that's all i can think of 
  again connection to `dynamoDB` or `S3` can be cached here. It won't be as fast as `ElastiCache` though.

Answer (score 0):

In Java it's not too hard to do.  Just create your cache outside of the handler:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class SampleHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(SampleHandler.class);

    private static Map<String, String> theCache = null;

    public SampleHandler() {
        logger.info( "filling cache...");

        theCache = new HashMap<>();

        theCache.put("key1", "value1");
        theCache.put("key2", "value2");
        theCache.put("key3", "value3");
        theCache.put("key4", "value4");
        theCache.put("key5", "value5");
    }

    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {
        logger.info("handlingRequest");
        LambdaLogger lambdaLogger = context.getLogger();

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(inputStream);

        String requestedKey = jsonNode.get("requestedKey").asText();

        if( theCache.containsKey( requestedKey )) {
            // read from the cache
            String result = "{\"requestedValue\": \"" + theCache.get(requestedKey) + "\"}";

            outputStream.write(result.getBytes());
        }

       logger.info("done with run, remaining time in ms is " + context.getRemainingTimeInMillis() );
    }
}
```

(run with the AWS cli with `aws lambda invoke --function-name lambda-cache-test --payload '{"requestedKey":"key4"}' out` with the output going the the file `out`)

When this runs with a "cold start" you'll see the "filling cache..." message and then the "handlingRequest" in the CloudWatch log.  As long as the Lambda is kept "warm" you will not see the cache message again.

Note that if you had hundreds of the same Lamda's running they would all have their own independent cache.  Ultimately this does what you want though - it's a lazy load of the cache during a cold start and the cache is reused for warm calls.